# Javascript form submit creates huge number of POST requests (multiple submit)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is a weird one, please feel free to edit the question or ask for more info if I haven't provided all the info.

I have a form (a timed quiz) that is automatically submitted if the user didn't submit it in a fixed amount of time and a countdown clock displayed on the page.

However, when time expires and the form is submitted, the browser gets into a weird state till it crushes, and the Apache log shows an endless list of POST requests. What could be causing this?

Even after I close down the browser window, the server still gets hit with the POST requests.

If I let the window open, Chrome will eventually display a failure message but the POST requests will still be coming in, long after this message is displayed (I would say up to a minute after). The error in question can be seen here, along with the Apache log file that records the POST requests coming on and on: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eci1z.jpg or if I manage to insert it here:
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eci1z.jpg

This is a Wordpress website but heavily customized by me. My .htaccess file is quite basic, I don't think this is the issue.

The same code works on another part of the site, to make things even harder to understand.

I also tested and got the same behavior on both WAMP (Apache 2.2.22/PHP 5.4.3) and a production server running PHP 5.5 (not sure about Apache version).

PHP:

```
define('REDIRECT_LINK', '/finish-free-iq-test.php');
```

Javascript:

```
function update_time_remaining() {
    var start_time_millis = Math.floor(jQuery("#start_time").val());
    var redir_to = "<?php echo REDIRECT_LINK; ?>";
    var test_duration = <?php echo Question::get_duration($questionSetID) * 1000;?>;
    var now = new Date();
    var remainingTime = test_duration - (now.getTime() - start_time_millis);
    if (remainingTime <= 0) {
//        console.log("time is out, redir to: " + redir_to);
//        alert("stop=");
        // force-submit the form
        jQuery("#answerForm").attr("action", redir_to);
        jQuery("#answerForm").submit();
    }
    else {
        var minutesRemaining = Math.floor(remainingTime / 60000);
        var secondsRemaining = Math.floor((remainingTime - minutesRemaining * 60000) / 1000);
        jQuery("#timer").html("Time remaining : " + (minutesRemaining<10?"0":"") + minutesRemaining + ":" + (secondsRemaining<10?"0":"") + secondsRemaining);
        //console.log(secondsRemaining);
    }   
}

// Things to do once the page has loaded (start the clock for example)
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#submitRow").hide();
    jQuery("#start_time").val(new Date().getTime() - <?php echo (time() - $timeStarted)*1000; ?>);
    update_time_remaining();
    // check every half a second so the ticking is consistent looking.
    window.setInterval("update_time_remaining()", 500);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="timer"></div> <br/>
<form id="answerForm" 
      method="POST" 
      action="<?php echo REDIRECT_LINK; ?>">

        <input id="submitRow" type="submit" name="go_next" value="Next question"> 

<?php echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"current\" value=\"$id\">"; ?>
<input type="hidden" name="answer" id="answer" value="-1">
<input type="hidden" name="start_time" id="start_time" value="<?php echo $jsTimeStarted; ?>">

</form>
```

Comment: @RamRaider, you mean `remainingTime`? aren't global variables bad practice?

Comment: So after time is over - you should `clearInterval`, so it never works again.

Comment: @u_mulder, clearInterval right before the submit() seems to have fixed this issues. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a glance, it looks like you don't have anything that stops the "update_time_remaining()" being called on a 500ms interval.

This means that the 'if (remainingTime <= 0) {' check gets called continuously, even after the timer goes below zero- and leads to repeated post calls until the page is unloaded.

Perhaps incorporate a boolean flag that allows the following to only be called once:

```
jQuery("#answerForm").submit();
```

A good solution would be to remove the interval that calls 'update_time_remaining()' after the submit has been called.

As an additional note, remember that because this is a javascript-only timing check, someone with enough expertise (and time) could simply disable the check happening, and submit the answers whenever they please. A good solution to this would be checking how long the person took to answer the question at the server-side.

Comment: nice one, Hiphop, it seems like you are on the right track. Can you explain what `page is unloaded` means? Thanks

Comment: Also, not sure how come this code is working on another page of the site... It displays another test, but everything is exactly the same functionality-wise, and works. But you are correct, the function is called on and on.

Comment: By unloaded I mean the browser is no longer running javascript on that page, either the tab was closed or they went to another page on the site.

Comment: And it could work on another page because the 'unload' happens faster (they get diverted to another page immediately perhaps), or because submitting multiple POSTs just doesn't happen to cause an error further up the chain. It might still be doing it on the other page though; check it out with the network tab of the web inspector in chrome to see what's getting sent there.

Comment: Well, the strange thing is, like I said, the server logs records POST requests even after the tab was closed. Can't go to another page as the browser is frozen at that moment. Not sure if you managed to take a look at the image I uploaded (I had some issues uploading it).

Comment: you didn't mention the clearInterval solution. Adding clearInterval right before the submit() seems to have fixed this issue. But I had to declare a global variable which I don't particularly enjoy.

Comment: That's a tricky one- I can't say anything with certainty, but I imagine chrome had queued up more requests internally, perhaps even before they were shown. Chrome might still have an intention to execute pending POST requests, and will do that in the background. Example scenario: You queue 100 requests, and Chrome processes them at 5reqs/second. You process 50 of them before closing the tab. Chrome might still try and execute the remaining requests anyways, over the course of the next 10 seconds. Guesswork on my part here.

Comment: Perhaps I could have been clearer, but I did say "A good solution would be to remove the interval..." in the original answer. clearInterval() is the mechanism to achieve that